# Backing up Content of the Azure API Management developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've extended the Developer Portal in the Azure API Management by creating a new page in the content section.

This is great however I'd like to backup the content I've written to an offline storage (or source control) in the worst happens and the APIm is lost.

Is there a simple way of backing up these content pages?

Answer (score 1):

There are generally 2 ways to manage "backups" in API Management: backups and source control. I'll give link to both methods (as its quite a long read, no point in pasting it here). As far as I can tell both these methods should work in your case.

[Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore) and [source control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git)

Comment: I tried the source control option but its seems to expose everything but the content. I see email templates, css files, API configuration etc but no content files.

Comment: Content didn't include in the source control method. [for more include please visit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42c7f901-212c-420f-956a-fe584e871ccc/automation-of-portal-styles-using-api-or-equivalent-approach?forum=azureapimgmt)              [Please vote this wish in APIM](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34378729-ability-to-import-and-export-cms-content-mangament)